# Can't compare index() and an integer?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Im very confused. Im trying to compare the index() of some li elements to a changing integer var, yet even when printing both to console and trying `parseInt()` on both, this or any comparison returns false:

```
$(this).index() <= this.midMenuIndex
```

Full code:

```js
if (event.key == "ArrowRight") {
  if (this.midMenuIndex < 2) {
    this.midMenuIndex++;
  }
} else if (event.key == "ArrowLeft") {
  if (this.midMenuIndex > 0) {
    this.midMenuIndex--;
  }
}

$('.dots li').each(function(){
  console.log(parseInt($(this).index()) == this.midMenuIndex);
```

Ive also tried `$(this).index() == this.midMenuIndex` and nothing. Both print the numbers 0-2 respectively to console. Why doesn't comparison work here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While I can't be certain what `this` is referring to in *most* of your code, I can tell you that `$('.dots li').each(function() { ... }` *will change what `this` refers to*. Per [jQuery's documentation](https://api.jquery.com/Types/#Element):

> Whenever you call jQuery's `.each()` method, the context of the callback function — `this` — is set to a DOM element.

This means that in most of  your code, `this.midMenuIndex` will refer to the same value, however on your last line (*inside* the `.each(function() { ... })`), `this.midMenuIndex` will be referring to a `midMenuIndex` property on the current element being iterated.

To keep a reference to the "outer" `this`, store it as a variable:

```js
const self = this;
if (event.key == "ArrowRight") {
  if (self.midMenuIndex < 2) {
    self.midMenuIndex++;
  }
} else if (event.key == "ArrowLeft") {
  if (self.midMenuIndex > 0) {
    self.midMenuIndex--;
  }
}

$('.dots li').each(function() {
  console.log(parseInt($(this).index()) == self.midMenuIndex);
});
```